# Why does ZnO turn yellow when it is hot?

Tags: physical-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, crystal-structure, color

Why does ZnO's color become yellow when it is hot? I have read that it is because of physical properties, but I need a more elaborate explanation.

Comment: I read on wikipedia that it is a thermochrome compound (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermochromism )

Comment: If anyone is interested, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Pp2CefdXVw) shows the effect very well, and also touches on the explanation.

Comment: IT is most likely Thermally induced charge transfer between the inherently unstable oxide ion and the Zinc ion resulting in an electronic transition that absorbs blue light. Observe it under a photographic safe light it will not change color.

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-center

Answer (score 15):

The **thermochromism** of $\ce{ZnO}$ results from a minor loss of oxygen upon heating to temperatures around 800 °C, i.e. a non-stoichiometric $\ce{Zn$_{1+x}$O}$ with $x = 7 \times 10^{-5}$ is formed.

Under air, this effect is reversible. Heating (and cooling) of the material while hooked up to a vacuum pump might result in a more persistent colour change.

Comment: So heating causes $\ce{2O^{2-}}$ to be oxidized to $\ce{O2}$? That seems unlikely to me. Does something else happen to the $\ce{O^{2-}}$?

Comment: This may explain the chemical change but it doesn't explain the reason behind the colour change. What causes the colour?

Comment: F centres are the reason for the colour see e.g. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-center

Comment: O= is endothermic I propose that  Zn++ O=  becomes Zn+O-  This can be checked by heating in an inert, argon atmosphere.  The color change should still be reversible.

Answer (score 7):

When you heat $\ce{ZnO}$ then Oxygen leaves as $\ce{O2}$ leaving behind $\ce{Zn^{2+}}$ and 2 electrons. $\ce{Zn^{2+}}$ and the 2 electrons move to the interstitial sites of the crystal . This provides excess electrons in the crystal lattice of $\ce{ZnO}$. When light falls on these crystals then these electrons absorb a part of the light in the visible region and hence impart a yellow colour to the $\ce{ZnO}$.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably because the [band gap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band_gap) closes, thus allowing electrons from the valence band to be elevated into the conduction band (by absorbing blue light, which makes the reflected color yellow).

Answer (score 1):

Upon heating ZnO, anionic vacancies are created and when an electron occupies that vacancy it imparts yellow colour (metal excess defect/f-centre).

Comment: It would be nice to flesh this answer out a bit, particularly on the color centers and their population vs temperature in thermodynamic equilibrium.

Answer (score -1):

In $\ce{ZnO}$, $\ce{Zn}$ is present in the 2+ oxidation state, and the d subshell has 10 electron, and the s subshell has 0. When $\ce{ZnO}$ is heated there is a transition of electron from d to s subshell, causing it to become yellow, and on cooling it becomes white.